# multiple definition of `function' error occurring on the same line as "first defined here"

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors, include, function-definition

error log

```
paging.c: In function ‘setup_paging_structures’:
paging.c:7: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’
rm -f bootimg
gcc -nostdlib -static boot.o paging.o x86_desc.o i8259.o kernel.o lib.o paging.o tests.o -Ttext=0x400000 -o bootimg
paging.o: In function `setup_paging_structures':
/workdirmain/work/mp3_group_31/student-distrib/paging.c:4: multiple definition of `setup_paging_structures'
paging.o:/workdirmain/work/mp3_group_31/student-distrib/paging.c:4: first defined here
paging.o: In function `initialize_paging':
/workdirmain/work/mp3_group_31/student-distrib/paging.c:13: multiple definition of `initialize_paging'
paging.o:/workdirmain/work/mp3_group_31/student-distrib/paging.c:13: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bootimg] Error 1
```

Here's what my paging.h file looks like:

```
#ifndef _PAGING_H
#define _PAGING_H

#include "types.h"

#define TOTAL_ENTRIES 1024

extern void setup_paging_structures();
extern void initialize_paging();

#endif
```

Paging.c below:

```
#include "paging.h" //include header files

void setup_paging_structures(){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < TOTAL_ENTRIES; i++){
        printf("weird");
    }
    return;
}

void initialize_paging(){
    setup_paging_structures();
    return;
}
```

**Note, I have not called the functions yet.**

The command I'm using is "sudo make" (Makefile was given to me. I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to modify it):

```
# Makefile for OS project
# To build, first `make dep`, them `make`. Everything should be automatic.
# Will compile all *.c and *.S files in the current directory.


# Flags to use when compiling, preprocessing, assembling, and linking
CFLAGS+=-Wall -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostdlib
ASFLAGS+=
LDFLAGS+=-nostdlib -static
CC=gcc

#If you have any .h files in another directory, add -I<dir> to this line
CPPFLAGS+=-nostdinc -g

# This generates the list of source files
SRC=$(wildcard *.S) $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard */*.S) $(wildcard */*.c)

# This generates the list of .o files. The order matters, boot.o must be first
OBJS=boot.o
OBJS+=$(filter-out boot.o,$(patsubst %.S,%.o,$(filter %.S,$(SRC))))
OBJS+=$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(filter %.c,$(SRC)))

bootimg: Makefile $(OBJS)
    rm -f bootimg
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -Ttext=0x400000 -o bootimg
    sudo ./debug.sh

dep: Makefile.dep

Makefile.dep: $(SRC)
    $(CC) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $(SRC) > $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o */*.o Makefile.dep

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),dep)
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
include Makefile.dep
endif
endif
```

edit: I added updates to my post including the actual directories, the entire error log, and the contents of the Makefile I am using. This is also for a class that I'm currently taking, hence some of the things that were automatically given to me.

Comment: I think there are things you have not shown us. Please check that your code is a complete [mre] and also show the exact build command and exact build log.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Done. I've tried to be as comprehensive and include all the relevant info as possible.

Comment: `gcc -nostdlib -static boot.o paging.o x86_desc.o i8259.o kernel.o lib.o paging.o` The `paging.o` is being linked twice.

Comment: I don't see what you are referring to? I see ``gcc -nostdlib -static boot.o paging.o x86_desc.o i8259.o kernel.o lib.o paging.o The paging.o`` once in the error log but that's it.

Comment: What do you mean? Clearly that line I pasted in has `paging.o` twice. That is `gcc ... paging.o ... paging.o ...` If you link the same file twice then clearly it will have symbol clashes with itself.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I thought you were that error message was occurring twice instead of the paging.o occurring twice. 

Do you know how to fix it? I only created one paging.c and paging.h file.

Comment: Do you have a source file named "paging.S"? Or another "paging.c" in a subdirectory? Look at the lines `OBJS+=...` in the Makefile.

Comment: Yup that was it thanks!